# Can be ERC20 token name be in lowercase?

Tags: erc-20

Are the following token names correct?

- TOKeN
- token
- Token
- tOKEN

Comment: It also can be tOkEn, just to keep some pattern =)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Token name is just a string defined in an ERC20 standard: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol

```
string private _name;
string private _symbol;

constructor(string memory name_, string memory symbol_) {
  _name = name_;
  _symbol = symbol_;
}

function name() public view virtual override returns (string memory) {
  return _name;
}

function symbol() public view virtual override returns (string memory) {
  return _symbol;
}
```

Comment: Agreed, I had some crazy token names, never had a problem.